# log4j - print to console But not to file

Tags: log4j

I'm using this log4j.properties file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ALL,console

log4j.appender.console = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern = %d %p %t %c - %m%n

log4j.appender.A=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.A.File=log/LotteryLogger.log 
log4j.appender.A.MaxFileSize=2MB
log4j.appender.A.MaxBackupIndex=3
log4j.appender.A.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p %t %c - %m%n
log4j.category.com.test.controller=INFO,A
```

In my TestController I have

```
private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestController.class);
```

Why can't print to file?

Btw, this is a web app
when i tried this on simple stand alone application it worked great.

Comment: Which package is `TestController` in?

Answer (score 1):

If you say that it works well in your IDE and that it doesn't work as a webapp, it is possible that you are placing your log4j.properties file in the wrong location.

When running your application from the command line you are likely passing it the JVM argument:
log4j.configuration=/path/to/my/file/log4j.properties

In the context of a webapp the servlet container will be in charge of loading the log4j configuration.
This is usually done by loading the log4j.properties/xml file that is located under WEB-INF/classes

Another alternative is to add it to the CATALINA_OPS environment variable, you can look [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#defaultInit) for more detail.

**EDIT**: if you are sure that file permissions are OK, and that both files are indeed loaded I would suggest running log4j in debug mode, in this mode log4j will print out internal messages, such as what file it is loading and what appenders are being configured. this is your best bet at debugging.

To use log4j in debug mode I think you must have a [log4j XML configuration](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jXmlFormat) and add the attribute `debug="true"` to the root element, once done (and assuming the configuration file is actually read) you should see exactly what log4j is doing.

Comment: I ment When I used the same properties file on a diffrent project 

  which is not web application it work - meaning the log file was 

  created and logs were written into it.


  But when I build a web application (diffrenet project)

  I was able to print only logs to console and not to file.

  Both project I ran from eclipse IDE and not from command line..

  log4j.properties file locate on the write place because if not i won't be able to print to console either..

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, do you mean you run a web server via eclipse, such as Jetty or Tomcat, or are you just running unit tests and Main classes?

Comment: Asaf , 


Thanks For the Tip (log4j.xml) it clarified many things to me.


I am able to see exactly what log4 is doing.


But Still can't understand why the logs are not printed to log file 


nothing is written with the DEBUG manner you suggested..

Answer (score 1):

I followed the below steps and it worked for me:

1) Place ur log4j.properties file in the following:
WEB-INF/classes

2) Place the log4jXXX.jar file in the application lib folder under the WEB-INF folder. If we do not follow this step then it will pick up the jar file already there in the jboss server and work with JBOSS existing logs settings mentioned in jboss-log4j.xml

Please try if it resolve ur problem.

Thanks

Ankit Adlakha

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried `log4j.rootLogger=ALL,console,A` ? I think `A` is missing in the first line. I append an example file that I'm using.

```
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, stdout, stderr, dailyfile

log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold = INFO
log4j.appender.stdout = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %5p %m (%C::%M:%L)%n

log4j.appender.stderr.Threshold = ERROR
log4j.appender.stderr = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stderr.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stderr.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %5p %m (%C::%M:%L)%n

log4j.appender.dailyfile.Threshold = DEBUG
log4j.appender.dailyfile = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.dailyfile.File = ./log/Torpedo.log
log4j.appender.dailyfile.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.dailyfile.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %5p {%t} %m (%C::%M:%L)%n

log4j.appender.dailyfile.DatePattern ='.'yyyy-MM-dd
```

Answer (score 0):

I had absolutely the same problem. File was created, but without any loggs in it just in console. And it was because of incorrect dependencies in maven project in my case.

My `log4j.properties` file was:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file

# Direct log messages to a log file
# configuration to print into file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=[%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
# Set the name of the file
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\log\\logging.log
# Set the append to false, overwrite
log4j.appender.file.Append=false
```

And I used in POM:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Yes, it created for me file where I needed it, but logs were in console. Then I changed it to another dependency like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>
</dependency>
```

And I finally got it in file instead of console. Even without any explicit commands like `PropertyConfigurator.configure()`.

P.S. And be careful with configuration in properties file. Because in your code-example is `console`, but you need to use `file`.